# Java - compare an arrays of values

Tags: java, arrays, compare

```
String isoArray[] = {"020","784","004","028"};

if(!("020".equals(element[2]) || "784".equals(element[2]) || "004".equals(element[2]) || "028".equals(element[2]))){
            country a = new country(element[4], element[5], element[7]);
            countries.add(a);
}
```

Is there an easier way of comparing these strings without using loops?

Comment: What's wrong with loops. Understanding your reason may help with answers.

Comment: Heavily comparison inside a if statement is considered as a bad practice. It's so ugly, error-prone and hard to read. You always have a better way to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 12):

Try  below code.

```
if (Arrays.asList(isoArray).contains("YOUR_STRING"))
```

Comment: Beware that the implementation of `.contains()` probably uses loops

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Java 7 then you can use the switch-case on String constants as well.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the context of the problem it is hard to give an answer.

The most popular way (and widely taught way) to compare/search/organize arrays is with loops. One such solution is a bubble sort alg type loop.

```
for(int x = 0; x < array1.size(); x++){
   for(int y = 0; y < array2.size(); y++){
       if(array1[x].compare(array2[y]==0)
           Then they are equal 
       else
           They are not equal
    }
}
```

This is by far the fastest way to do something simple with multiple arrays

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the type you want to use is a Set

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>();
mySet.add("020");
mySet.add("784");
mySet.add("004");
mySet.add("028");

if(!mySet.contains(element[2])){
    country a = new country(element[4], element[5], element[7]);
    countries.add(a);
}
```

- `HashSet` will use hashing to look up the value.
- `TreeSet` will do a binary tree search.

Answer (score 0):

My friend, from your example it looks like you are trying to see whether `element[2]` is contained in an array of values.  As @Real said, you can convert the array to a list just so that you can use the list's `contains` predicate.  Well guess what?  The `contains` predicate is just a loop.

I despise code that contains gratuitous many-time conversions like this.  It spawns garbage. It is the code that today runs fine because your data are of size `N` and dies five years from now when your company has gone public and the data are now size `100000 * N`.  Don't die with it.

So the choices are obvious.  You can use an `ArrayList` with a single conversion to hold your array from the start:

```
ArrayList<String> isoArray = Arrays.asList(new String [] {"020", "784", "004", "028"});

...

    if (!isoArray.contains(element[2])) {
        country a = new country(element[4], element[5], element[7]);
        countries.add(a);
    }
```

Or you can implement your own contains method that works on bare arrays:

```
static public boolean contains(Object [] a, Object item) {
    for (Object aItem : a) if (item.equals(aItem)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

You'll want to consolidate utility functions like this in a class (of mostly static functions) called something like (tada!) `Utility`.  Incidently, this is why the good Lord gave us loops and functions.  Now,

```
String isoArray[] = {"020", "784", "004", "028"};

...

    if (!contains(isoArray, element[2])) {
        country a = new country(element[4], element[5], element[7]);
        countries.add(a);
    }
```

and all is right with the world...

There is another way if you can put your table of values in sorted order: Use the `Arrays` binary search routines.

```
String isoArray[] = {"004", "020", "028", "784"};

...

    if (Arrays.binarySearch(isoArray, element[2]) >= 0) {
        country a = new country(element[4], element[5], element[7]);
        countries.add(a);
    }
```